# Is there a more pythonic way of parsing my table using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, strip

I'm a relative newbie to Python. I've a html page with a table similar to the one below. That I would like to parse in and process that data in a neater more pythonic way.

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr><td><b>Test Results</b></td><td><b>Log File</b></td><td><b>Passes</b></td><td><b>Fails</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Test suite A</b></td><td><a href="A_logs.html">Logs</a></td><td><b>10</b></td><td><b>0</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Test suite B</b></td><td><a href="B_logs.html">Logs</a></td><td><b>20</b></td><td><b>0</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Test suite C</b></td><td><a href="C_logs.html">Logs</a></td><td><b>15</b></td><td><b>0</b></td></tr>
</table>
```

Using BeautifulSoup I've parsed in the table.

```
results_table = tables[0] # This will get the first table on the page.
table_rows = my_table.findChildren(['th','tr'])

for i in table_rows:
    text = str(i)
    print( "All rows:: {0}\n".format(text))
    if "Test suite A" in text:
        print( "Test Suite: {0}".format(text))
        # strip out html characters
        list = str(BeautifulSoup(text).findAll( text = True )) 
        # strip out any further stray characters such as [,] 
        list = re.sub("[\'\[\]]", "", list) 
        list = list.split(',') # split my list entries by comma
        print("Test: {0}".format(str(list[0])))
        print("Logs: {0}".format(str(list[1])))
        print("Pass: {0}".format(str(list[3])))
        print("Fail: {0}".format(str(list[4])))
```

So that's my code that does everything I want it to. I'm just wondering if there is a more pythonic way to do it. Ignoring the print statements as I plan to put this into its own method passing in the results table and return pass, fail, logs, test.

So..

```
def parseHtml(results_table)
    # split out all rows in my table into a list
    table_rows = my_table.findChildren(['th','tr'])
    for i in table_rows:
        text = str(i)
        if "Test suite A" in text:
            # strip out html characters
            list = str(BeautifulSoup(text).findAll( text = True )) 
            # strip out any further stray characters such as [,] 
            list = re.sub("[\'\[\]]", "", list) 
            # split my list entries by comma
            list = list.split(',') 
     return (list[0],list[1],list[3],list[4])
```

Comment: start by not using list as a variable name, also why are you casting find_all as a str?

Comment: what exactly do you want to extract?

Comment: To start off with, don't name your variable `list`.

Comment: I was casting find_all as a str because re.sub throws an error when stripping out the unwanted characters. Also, I want to extract the values in each of the table cells. Which I am doing. I just wanted to know if there was a neater more, pythonic / compact way of doing it.

Comment: Using re defeats the purpose of using beautifulsoup

Comment: I find that when I use str(BeautifulSoup(cell_contents).findAll( text = True )) I get left with ['Test Suite A', 'etc', 'etc', 81', '0']. But when I perform the split to get each cell entry, the first and last cells come with ['Test Suite A or 0'] instead of Test Suite A or 0 without the square brackets and each cell in between comes with apostrophes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html="""<table border="1">
    <tr><td><b>Test Results</b></td><td><b>Log File</b></td><td><b>Passes</b></td><td><b>Fails</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Test suite A</b></td><td><a href="A_logs.html">Logs</a></td><td><b>10</b></td><td><b>0</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Test suite B</b></td><td><a href="B_logs.html">Logs</a></td><td><b>20</b></td><td><b>0</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Test suite C</b></td><td><a href="C_logs.html">Logs</a></td><td><b>15</b></td><td><b>0</b></td></tr>
</table>"""


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
data = soup.find_all("b")  # this will be your table

# ignore Test Result etc.. and get Test suite A ... from each row
data = (data[4:][i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(data[4:]),3))
# get all log file names 
logs = iter(x["href"] for x in soup.find_all("a",href=True))

# unpack each subelement and print the tag text
for a, b, c in data:
    print("Test: {}, Log: {}, Pass: {}, Fail: {}".format(a.text ,next(logs),b.text, c.text))


Test: Test suite A, Log: A_logs.html, Pass: 10, Fail: 0
Test: Test suite B, Log: B_logs.html, Pass: 20, Fail: 0
Test: Test suite C, Log: C_logs.html, Pass: 15, Fail: 0
```

Don't use `list` as a variable name as it shadows the python `list`, if you want to get elements from your sublists from your find_all calls either  iterate over or index, don't use re.

Answer (score -1):

In such a situation I would tend to iterate over 'tr' and then 'td'

```
bs_table = BeautifulSoup(my_table)
ls_rows = []
for ls_tr in bs_table.findAll('tr'):
  ls_rows.append([td_bloc.text for td_bloc in ls_tr.findAll('td')])
```